# Stop io buffers from flushing in C

Tags: c++, c, buffer

Is it possible to stop an io buffer from flushing itself in C/C++?

To get maximum performance, I'm trying to save data and then flush after an operation is complete.

I can just write to an array and then print that out later, I was just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Have you actually identified that it's the flushing that is causing the problem. If you are writing large amounts of data to a file (and you have removed the `endl` in favour of a `'\n'` if you are using iostream), it is likely that the hard-disk is the limiting factor. Flushing the buffer won't make a difference if you are bound by the actual speed of the hard-drive.

Comment: That's a valid point. In this case, the data won't be more than a few megabytes, but for other cases that can cause problems. Is there a way in C to ask the OS to allocate ram instead of page file?

Comment: One of the fastest ways to read/write a file is to use "memory mapped files". This means you use `mmap` (in Linux/MacOS/other Unix) or `MapViewOfFile` (Windows), and write to the memory instead of a file. I still suspect flushing is not really an issue, but the memory mapped file uses a better interface to write the data to the file, because it doesn't have to double-buffer the data - it can write directly from the memory page that it assigned to that location in the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the size of the buffer by using a call to `setvbuf`.

Comment: Or remove the buffering with the very same function and use your own buffer. This grants you more control and prevents small flushes when you exceed the buffer by, say, 1B.